# Is there a way to specify timeout in worklight connect method call in Android or iOS library?

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I am testing my native app with a slower internet connection and worklight connect times out:

Is there a way to specify timeout value for worklight connect in both Objective-C client-side API for native iOS and Java client-side API for Android ? (I know one can specify timeout for method invocation and it seems one can specify timeout for connect in worklight javascript API).

These are the piece of native codes I'm working with:

In Android:

```
final WLClient wlClient = WLClient.createInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());
WConnectionListener connectListener = new WConnectionListener(serviceCallback);
wlClient.connect(connectListener);
```

In iOS:

```
WConnectListener *connectListener = [[WConnectListener alloc] init];
[[WLClient sharedInstance] wlConnectWithDelegate:connectListener];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like setting the timeout for WLClient connect is not exposed in either Android or iOS native projects. Much like the invokeProcedure function, the connect function uses a WLRequestOptions object to set the timeout. However, unlike the invokeProcedure function, connect does not allow the user to pass in their own WLRequestOptions object. It creates one internally and uses the default timeout.

I will log a defect for both the Android and iOS environments.